`/usr/bin/extension-manager` vs. `/usr/bin/gnome-extensions-app`
There are two different tools for GNOME extension management in GNOME 46:

Extension Manager: /usr/bin/extension-manager
and
Extensions: /usr/bin/gnome-extensions-app.

They have slightly different user interface and functionality.
Which is the one recommended (i.e. officially supported by GNOME) and why do we have two different tools?

The extension manager does the work of the extensions and allows you to search and download extensions

However it seems to have a problem of not updating or prompting for updates for already installed extensions.

Yes, It seems that it does not update (maybe a good idea),  But last time I got a msg. when I started my computer.

gnome-shell-extension-manager/noble,now 0.5.0-1build1 amd64 [installed] I think v.0.5.1 is the latest version
